# Why does my PermissionsAndroid Request always return granted?

Tags: react-native

For my React Native App, my PermissionsAndroid Modal pops up, but no matter which selection I hit, it always returns granted. I'd like for the other request types to appear when hitting Cancel or Ask Me Later

```
requestLocationPermission = async () => {
try {
   const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
     PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
     {
       title: "Location Access",
       message:
         "MKP Mobile needs your current location " +
         "so that it can find the closest I-groups near you",
       buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
       buttonNegative: "Cancel",
       buttonPositive: "OK"
     }
   );
   console.log("GRANTED! " , granted);
   console.log("GRANTED! " , PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED);
   if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
     this.getLocation();
   } else {
     this.searchGroups();
   }
 } catch (err) {
   console.warn(err);
 }
}
```